# Send file from windows local host to remote server via ssh

Tags: ssh, scp, winscp

How can I send any file from a windows local host to a remote server via ssh? If possible, using only shell command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#operations) does just that, doesn't it? And as the linked docs would promise, can do it from command line only too as per `/upload` parameter.